# Android: Storage and camera permission

Tags: android, react-native

My question is specific to Android 11. Since Android 11, we now have concept of scoped storage. I have read many answers on SO but I am still confused.

Few specs of my project:

```
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
```

**WHAT I UNDERSTAND FROM SCOPED STORAGE IN ANDROID 11:**

Earlier any app can read/write anywhere in the filesystem. Now, an app can read/write only in its **private** directory (excluding a few 'generally available' directories like DCIM). Is my understanding correct? (Question 1)

Private directory being : `Android/data/com.myappname/files/`

**THERE ARE 2 SCENARIOS IN MY APP:**

1. My app creates a file if its not created and then later reads it. I hardcoded now (for Android 11) the full path in my react native code: `Android/data/com.myappname/files/myfilename`. It is now working fine in android 11. Now my question is: Do I need to mention `READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in AndroidManifest.xml file?(Question 2) Secondly, do I need to ask user using dialog prompt in the app for any (storage) permission? (Question 3)
2. My app is using camera **and** gallery. For that I have only provided `CAMERA` permission in AndroidManifest.xml. Is it sufficient? What line should I add for reading from gallery? (Question 4)

Permissions from my AndroidManifest.xml is below:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" tools:node="remove" />
```

Comment: `(excluding few 'generally available' directories)` This is vague. Name those directories. Preferable full paths. You should better have written: `(and also a few 'generally available' directories)`. But still you should name them.

Comment: `the full path in my react native code: Android/data/com.myappname/files/myfilename`. Sorry but that is not a full path. It's a relative path. Full path would be:  `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myappname/files/myfilename`. For that path you do not have to request any permission.

Comment: You only need camera permssion. Strange... with a few tests you could investiga if you need them...

Comment: `My app is using .... gallery`. It is pretty unclear to me what an app does that uses the gallery. Vague again.

Comment: @blackapps. By gallery I mean that my app is reading the contents of the gallery for example - the photos placed in the gallery.

Comment: I have no idea what you do if you place fotos in 'the gallery'. You keep talking vague. And further you did not react to my other comments... Why?

Comment: @blackapps. The user using my app selects photo from the gallery (album) and sends the photo to cloud. Also I reacted to your other comment (regarding few generally available directories) by editing my question and mentioning it there

Comment: Sorry, did not see that. You mentioned one directory.. Your app does not need any permission to let the user pick fotos/files from device and use the obtained uri. For uploading you need INTERNET permission. You can easily check if your app needs any permission to create files in DCIM by just testing with and without permissions.

Answer (score 0):

1. For app-specific storage you don't need any permission to read and write.
2. If you want to get some permission from the user it's good to display a dialog as a consent explaining why you need this permission.
3. For Gallery below android 10 you need the `android.permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. For the Camera yes you only need to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`. You can add this line also `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />`  for Play Store.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can apply the permission `android.permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` conditionally. That is the permission is there for below android 10 and not for android 10 and above?

Comment: I don't know how to do in react-native but let me give you a pointer on how I can do it in native android ```if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 28) {

            // Todo

        }```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to provide Read, Write and Camera permissions.

**In AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

**In Info.plist:**(Below is just 1 example, you can add any permission you want)

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need photo library access to upload important documents</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need photo library access to upload important documents</string>
```

**If you want it programatically in react-native then:**

```
//ANDROID

import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';

if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      isReadGranted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      );
    }
if (isReadGranted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    //TODO
}

//IOS
import Permissions, {request} from 'react-native-permissions';
 
Permissions.check('ios.permission.PHOTO_LIBRARY');//checking for photo library permissions
request('ios.permission.PHOTO_LIBRARY');//requesting for photo lib permission
```